# Iphone simulator not getting location

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, core-location

Am getting users longitude and latitude in AppDelegate it asked for permission once when i deleted\Uninstall the app after reinstalled again on simulator it didn't ask for permission so the app keep crashing here is my code

```
 func initLocationManager() {

    if( CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse ||
        CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.Authorized){

        seenError = false
        locationFixAchieved = false
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        //        locationManager.locationServicesEnabled = true
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    }
}

// Location Manager Delegate stuff

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    if ((error) != nil) {
        if (seenError == false) {
            seenError = true
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if (locationFixAchieved == false) {
        locationFixAchieved = true
        var locationArray = locations as NSArray
        var locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as! CLLocation
        var coord = locationObj.coordinate

        LATITUDE = coord.latitude
        LONGITUDE = coord.longitude

        print(coord.latitude)
        print(coord.longitude)
    }
}



func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
                     didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    var shouldIAllow = false

    switch status {
    case CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
        locationStatus = "Restricted Access to location"
    case CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
        locationStatus = "User denied access to location"
    case CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
        locationStatus = "Status not determined"
    default:
        locationStatus = "Allowed to location Access"
        shouldIAllow = true
    }
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("LabelHasbeenUpdated", object: nil)
    if (shouldIAllow == true) {
        NSLog("Location to Allowed")
        // Start location services
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    } else {
        NSLog("Denied access: \(locationStatus)")
    }
}
```

Comment: So it wont work on the simulator?

Comment: It didnt work still. How can i get user location with swift

Comment: Where do you call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`?

Comment: it works on simulator.
click on simulator.go to debug menu in xcode.than go to location.you can select location from here

Comment: Am using `requestAlwaysAuthorization`

Comment: Yea i already did that

Comment: Ok, but that call is inside an if that is only true if the user has already granted whenInUse permission, you need to put your always request outside of that if. The first thing you should do is request permission

Comment: Can you provide an answer please

Answer (score 1):

try to get user location at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions for first time then call this method for getting updated user location.

```
locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:AnyObject[]) {
println("locations = \(locations)")
gpsResult.text = "success"
}
```

Comment: But the user location will changed everytime

Comment: I want to get the user location each time the app is launched

Comment: my answer works for to get the user location each time the app is launched.   to get get updated user location call